# Reading raster in Python to Clip USGS 3DEM?

Tags: arcpy, raster, clip

I want to clip the elevation data (3DEM) downloaded from USGS website. The raster-clip tool "Clip (data management)" in ArcGIS Pro works very well. However, I cannot clip it using the python function "arcpy.Clip_management()" .

The error report that the raster file is not exist or not support. I have tried different ways to read it, such as:

~grdn39w075.tif/Band_1   This is used by the Clip tool in Arcgis Pro
~grdn39w075.tif_Band_1 
~grdn39w075/Band_1

None of them can read the 3DEM file successfully.

Python code:

```
in_raster= "C:/Users/Desktop/Elevation/Tiles/grdn42w075.tif/Band_1"
for i in range(0,9):
 buffer = shp_list[i]
 out_id=num_buffer=re.findall('\d+', shp_list[i])
 out_path="C:/Users/Desktop/LUR_DM/GIS/Elevation/n42w75/"
 arcpy.Clip_management(in_raster,buffer,"n42w75_"+ out_id[1],
"C:/Users/Desktop/Documents/ArcGIS/Projects/LUR/LUR.gdb","99999","ClippingGeometry", "MAINTAIN_EXTENT")
```

Comment: `~/` means nothing in Windows, try using the full path including the drive letter

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. I use the full path in my code. To protect the ID credential in our school, I use ~ to represent the first part of path.

Comment: Ah, gotcha.  To debug, print your output file path that you're building and make sure that looks valid.  Try arcpy.Exists() on the input file to make sure that's getting found correctly

Comment: I suggest deleting '~' and replacing it with some dummy pseudonym like C:/Users/SomeUser/, for clarity to other readers.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is here:

```
.../grdn42w075.tif/Band_1
```

A .tif file, on the OS, is the end of a path, so `/Band_1` doesn't make sense when Python tries to look for that path. If you're just going for that .tif file, simply delete `/Band_1`. All existing bands in the GeoTiff should get clipped by default by the Arc tool.

If `grdn42w075.tif` is in fact a directory, you might need to supply the file extension for the file `Band_1`. I suggest not naming your directories that way, and please use 4 spaces when indenting in Python :)